# How do I get this validationTextBox to focus?

Tags: javascript, dojo

After performing an ajax request if the input in the form was wrong I am trying to get this validatationTextBox to be focussed on and display an indicator message showing the problem.

The code is:

```
dijit.byId("passwordField").focusNode.focus()
```

The form element is as mentioned a validationTextBox.

The matter that is confusing me even further is that before in dojo 1.5, this piece of code was simply `dijit.byId("passwordField").focus()` and this worked fine. How can I fix this?

I have also tried :

```
require(["dijit/focus"],function(focusU){ 
  focusU.focus(dojo.byId("ID"));});
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

If the dijit.widget.focus() fails, then the _FocuxMixin is not loaded properly during its startup.

With any dijit.form.Type, you should be able to successfully gain focus via:

```
dijit.byId('ID').focus();
```

I think youre confusing DOM event focus with widget focus handling. If you fire `widget.focusNode.focus` - you will not benifit from the messaging in `ValidationTextBox` in any browser.

Comment: I have already tried the dijit.byId("ID").focus(). In fact that was the first thing I did try. But that did not work.I tried the focusNode way of doing it because in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801039/dojo-set-validationtextbox-to-blur that was the answer. But neither of the ways are working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qQcbq/1/ it does work, set the `required` property and it will assert focusmixin

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?

Comment: If you require 'dijit/registry' as 'registry' registry.byId('ID').focus() works for me. Only if you want to focus the ValidationTextBox initially you should set the html5 autofocus attribute on the ValidationTextBox node.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this in the form tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load
                (
                function () {
                    window.setTimeout(focus, 1);
                }
                )
        function focus() {
            if (document.getElementById('txtComm1') != null) {
                if (document.getElementById('txtComm1').disabled != true) {
                    document.getElementById('txtComm1').focus();
                }
            }
        }      

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form fields are inside a `dijit/Dialog`, the `Dialog` will automatically focus on the first input. You can disable this behaviour by setting:

```
autofocus: false
```

on the Dialog, after which,

```
widget.focus();
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    widget.focus();
}, 100);
```